# Scheduling a local notification when the app is terminated

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, localnotification, unusernotificationcenter

My goal is to create a local notification that will trigger if the user has not launched the app for 2 weeks. I use a *Manager* class to handle the scheduling of the app's local notifications.

This is my current solution:

```
func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
    NotificationManager.shared.schedule(notification)
}
```

However, `applicationWillTerminate` is not going to be called - and thus the notification will not be scheduled - **if the app is terminated while it is in the background** (i.e. it is swiped from the dock).

Are there any workarounds to this?

One workaround I thought about was to schedule the notification whenever the app enters the background, and then call `removePendingNotificationRequests()` if the app becomes active again, as shown below:

```
func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    NotificationManager.shared.schedule(notification)
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
   UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removePendingNotificationRequests(withIdentifiers: ["notification"])
}
```

The issue with this is that it seems to me like a wasteful and suboptimal solution. Is there a more elegant solution than scheduling this notification

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are pretty close to the strategy I would use. Rather than schedule the notification when you enter the background, clear and schedule every time the app becomes active.

```
func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) { 
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removePendingNotificationRequests( withIdentifiers: ["notification"]
    NotificationManager.shared.schedule(notification)
}
```

Every time you launch, you should setup a notification for 2 weeks in the future. If they launch tomorrow, delete the old notification, and setup a new one for two week after that.

Comment: if the op sets the same identifier for the notification then no need to clear as it'll be over witted

Comment: You are right. I must have tunnel visioned on a previous implementation and needed a fresh set of eyes to look it over. I ended up scheduling the notification directly in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` to simplify the code even further (although your answer is just as valid).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the current workaround if you didn't said , actually the background experience for ios apps running in background is very poor and there is no guarantee `applicationWillTerminate` to be called , even to stay alive until the scheduling happens , as IOS always cares about app when it's in front and nearly gives up to 5 minutes to the app when it's sent to background to terminate and that will be dramatically less if the user is opening multiple apps at the same time

You can create a background fetch process to schedule it while the app is closed , but this will have more hassles than the current